# Redundant condition check before assignment suggestion for C# in Resharper 5

Tags: c#, properties, resharper, setter, getter

Is the condition check really redundant in the following sample?:

```
public class MyClass     {
    public bool MyProperty { get; set; }

    public void DoSomething(bool newValue) {
        // R# says: redundant condition check before assignment
        // on the following line:
        if (MyProperty != newValue) { // <======
            MyProperty = newValue;
        }
    }
}
```

I know that either way `MyProperty` will be set to `newValue`, but is the **check** redundant?

In Adobe Flex, the [getter is called implicitly by the VM](http://blogs.soph-ware.com/?p=4) its running on whenever a setter is called even though no explicit check is being made. The end result is that checking before an assignment results in two checks, one explicit and one implicit, resulting in a redundant check. Does anything similar happen in C#?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are only two situations where I've seen this type of check.

The first is when there is an additional line of code which sets another property on the object to True to indicate that the object has been modified.  This is typically used when trying to decide whether to persist the state of the object to something like a database.

The second situation is when the types in question are immutable.  You might want to avoid setting the value and therefore creating a new string, for example, when the values are the same.  Even then, I've only seen it in certain apps where memory usage is critical.

Comment: In my case it's around a windows forms `TopMost` property which does have side-effects. Very good points about the immutable values.

Comment: Another use is when updating a UI element only when values are changed.

Answer (score 4):

In this specific case, it's logically redundant, since there is no code being executed in the getter - just a straight wrapper around a private field. If you're in the habit of putting stuff in your getter that would have side effects, I'd say to disable that R# warning.

Might be worth trying to put something in the getter of the property, and see if ReSharper still thinks it's redundant. If it does, then I'd call that a R# bug.

Comment: I changed the property to an `int` and incremented the value in the getter and I still see the same suggestion, so I'm going to consider it a Resharper bug.

Comment: Good to know, thanks - I'll keep my eyes open for that scenario in my stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the check is redundant. It would make more sense if you had an implementation of [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx), but then the check would be in the setter to avoid triggering the event if no actual change is done.

Answer (score 0):

if (`MyProperty != newValue`) IS redundant, leaving the line will yield the same result